# Multiprocessing crashes on big-data (OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files)

Tags: python, multiprocessing, dataset, oserror

I'm using python3.8 to transform .mp4 videos from the dataset (~700GB) to images (1 frame from every second of video) using multiprocessing, code below.

```
import os
import sys
import cv2

from pathlib import Path

from multiprocessing import Process

base_path = 'path_to_dataset'
images_dir = 'path_to_dataset_images'
image_fps = 1


def task(path, name):
    filename, file_extension = os.path.splitext(os.path.relpath(os.path.join(path, name), base_path))
    if file_extension != '.mp4':
        exit(0)

    video_path = os.path.join(path, name)
    image_path = os.path.join(images_dir, filename)
    extension = ".png"
    try:
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)
        fps = round(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))
        hop = round(fps / image_fps)
        curr_frame = 0
        while True:
            ret, frame = cap.read()
            if not ret:
                break
            if curr_frame % hop == 0:
                name = image_path + "_" + str(curr_frame) + extension
                Path(os.path.dirname(name)).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

                if cv2.imwrite(name, frame):
                    print(name + " saved")
                else:
                    print(name + " not saved!", file=sys.stderr)
            curr_frame += 1
    except:
        print(image_path + " failed due to error", file=sys.stderr)
    finally:
        cap.release()


def convert_to_image():
    # create all tasks
    processes = []
    for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(base_path):
        processes = processes + [Process(target=task, args=(path, name,)) for name in files]
    # start all processes
    for process in processes:
        process.start()
    # wait for all processes to complete
    for process in processes:
        process.join()
    # report that all tasks are completed
    print('Done', flush=True)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    convert_to_image()
```

Python gets the location of dataset files, creates a new folder with the dataset_image name, and maintains the folder structure of the original video dataset. The code is running with 8 cores and 128 GB of RAM. After like 8,5 hours of running (60+ hours of CPU time), it crashes on the error below. I've tried to use variants with or without a try-catch block without any improvement. Images are saved correctly as I want. Also, the data structure is perfectly fine.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "convert_to_images.py", line 72, in <module>
    convert_to_image()
  File "convert_to_images.py", line 59, in convert_to_image
    process.start()
  File "/home/user/.conda/envs/tf2.9/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 121, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "/home/user/.conda/envs/tf2.9/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/context.py", line 224, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
  File "/home/user/.conda/envs/tf2.9/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/context.py", line 277, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "/home/user/.conda/envs/tf2.9/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py", line 19, in __init__
    self._launch(process_obj)
  File "/home/user/.conda/envs/tf2.9/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py", line 69, in _launch
    child_r, parent_w = os.pipe()
OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files
```

Comment: Your code has the potential to open a lot of processes. Try with a fixed sized [Pool](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool) of processes.

Comment: What @KlausD. said and also one can increase the maximum amount of open file handles from os

Comment: @rasjani I don't have permission to increase the open file limit. This is running on the cluster.

Comment: As per KlausD, better to have a fixed pool. You will end up with better performance too because there is some overhead in starting a new process.